# Installing Alfine shifter with nexus 8 hub

Tags: shimano, shifter

My nexus shifter needs replacing and I don't like the twisting type of shifters so I wanted to use a trigger one with my nexus hub.

Can I use the Alfine SL-S503 with a nexus 8 internal hub?

I think I also need to replace my brake lever so I can install the shifter, what type of lever do I need for the Alfine SL-S503?

Comment: Did it work for you? I mean Alfine shifter with Nexus hub? I'm in [similar situation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/68416/), albeit I have a bit newer parts, it seems...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yep, same cable pull for the shifter.](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-IG-cable-pull.html)

Alfine shifters have the same bar real estate needs as most any other modern flatbar shifter, so you can use pretty much whatever you want that's compatible with your brake, which is its own question that you can find plenty of discussions on here.

Comment: I didn't know Nexus and Alfine were the same pull.  Can you please source a reference for this?  Not that you need to for this site, but so I can reference it in the future?

Comment: I linked to the best web reference I know for this.

Comment: Oh, got it, sorry, didn't see that was a link lol

Comment: Please, don't you know if this also works for newer parts? Concretely Shimano Nexus C6000 Revoshift (8s) (hub) and Shimano Alfine 7000 (8s)? I asked similar question [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/68416/).

Answer (score 4):

I have used the Alfine 8 rapid-fire type shifter with a Nexus 8 hub. It works much more positively than the twist grip shifter, no more jumping out of gear. The only downside is the gear display shows the engaged gears in the reverse sequence, as the cassette joint rotates in the opposite direction to the Alfine cassette joint, but the cable pull is exactly the same. that's why it's listed as incompatible.

Comment: Welcome to the site - that's useful and relevant information, thank you.