# What are the differences between the Alfine 8 and the Nexus 8?

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, nexus, alfine

I'm shopping for a new bike and I have a choice between one with the Alfine 8 and the other with the Nexus 8.

They seem to be pretty similar, but from what I could gather from forums here and there, the Alfine has more praise than the Nexus.

What are the actual differences between the two?

Answer (score 5):

Another significant difference is that the nexus is supplied with a grip/twist shifter:

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0412/5529/products/Nexus_20shifter_20SL-8S20_grande.jpeg?v=1429696938]

And the Alfine has a trigger/pod shifter:

[image: https://www.jensonusa.com/globalassets/product-images---all-assets/shimano/sl229a00.jpg]

Both shifters are intended to be used with the right hand.

Also note that the IGH has variable pull amounts between gears, so you cannot substitute a linear pull shifter from a derailleur setup.

Also see [Installing Alfine shifter with nexus 8 hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46848/installing-alfine-shifter-with-nexus-8-hub)

Comment: any difference it terms of efficiency? robustness? longevity? build quality?

Comment: @kokito can't answer sorry - the only nexus I've used was a 3 speed, 5 years old and never maintained so not a great comparison.  I personally ride an alfine11, and while it has quirks its a great wee hub, and far cheaper than a rolhoff.  To save this getting chatty, consider joining [chat] instead.

Comment: I have an Alfine 8. It has lasted 12 years so far. I previously had a Nexus. It didn't last that long. I replaced the trigger shifter by a twist shifter which works well with my Alfine

Comment: (further to my earlier comment) After 13 years my Alfine 8 stopped shifting reliably and I had to replace it (with another).

Answer (score 2):

To quote [Peter White Cycles](https://www.peterwhitecycles.com/Alfine.php):

> The main difference between Nexus and Alfine groups is that Alfine is designed for disc brakes, and Nexus is designed for roller brakes.

Alfine hubs use regular Centerlock discs. This means that you have a wide choice of discs, disc diameters and disc calipers from multiple vendors. For roller brakes, I have a feeling that your choice is pretty much limited by Shimano's own offerings.

Comment: Both work perfectly well with rim brakes.

Comment: both seems to work with disk brake too

Comment: The [CUBE Hyde Pro](https://www.cube.eu/en/2019/bikes/trekking/urban/hyde/cube-hyde-pro-blacknblue-2019/) has disc brakes on a Nexus hub. I understood that the Alfine was higher specification than the Nexus, but on the link in this answer the Nexus costs slightly more.

Comment: Yes, the SG-C6000-8D/SG-C6001-8D uses a disk brake ("D").