# Shimano Nexus with shift levers

Tags: shifter, drivetrain, internally-geared-hub, nexus, grip-shifter

Shimano Nexus usually comes with a twist shifts. Is it possible to also use shift levers with Nexus? Which ones?

More concretely, Shimano Nexus C6000 Revoshift (8s) (hub) and Shimano Alfine 7000 (8s) (levers), for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm under the impression that Nexus 8 and Alfine 8 shifters and hubs straight interchange... but even if I'm missing something there, Shimano themselves says you can use the Alfine SL-S503 Rapidfire shifter with Nexus 8.

[image: si.shimano.com]

Comment: Thank you very much! So according to the table Nexus C6000 is compatible with Alfine S503, but not with Afline S7000, correct? Btw., if anybody read this in the future, the manufacturer item number is ESLS503ALLL3 (S503). In the meantime I also found microShift SL-N758 shifter which claims to be Nexus Inter 8 compatible.

Comment: Yes, they're saying 503 interchanges but 7000 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the IGHs from shimano don't use a linear activation - you can't use any old shifter.

The amount of cable pulled between each gear are not the same.

So you need an Alfine or Nexus 8 speed trigger shifter for an 8 speed alfine or nexus.  They do exist.

(not sure about the cable pull on 3 speed hubs sorry.)

Comment: Thank you! And sorry, just checking if I parsed it correctly: Alfine is for Alfine only, Nexus is for Nexus only? Also, I made an edit to spell it out better.

Comment: @EcirHana I don't know  - but this question says they are swappable.     https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46848/installing-alfine-shifter-with-nexus-8-hub